# Remove from binary tree C#

Tags: c#, binary-tree

Hi I got a little problem with removing from binary tree in C#. I don't know why but this code doesn't work good ( my tree doesn't change after call'd remove method). Here is my code:

```
public class BinaryTree<T>
{
    public BinaryTree<T> Left, Right;
    public T Data;
    public BinaryTree()
    {
        this.Left = null;
        this.Right = null;
    }
}


public BinaryTree<T> FindNode(T value,ref BinaryTree<T> myTree)
{
    if (myTree == null) 
        return null;
    else
    {
        int result = Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(value, myTree.Data);
        if (result == 0)
            return myTree;
        else if (result > 0)
            return FindNode(value, ref myTree.Right);
        else if (result < 0)
            return FindNode(value, ref myTree.Left);
    }
    return myTree;
}

public void RemoveValue(T value,ref BinaryTree<T> myTree)
{
    BinaryTree<T> helper = new BinaryTree<T>();
    BinaryTree<T> MyTree = myTree;
    if (MyTree == null) return;
    MyTree =FindNode(value,ref MyTree);
    if (MyTree.Left == null || MyTree.Right == null)
        helper = MyTree;
    else
    {
        helper = MyTree.Left;
        while (helper.Right!=null)
            helper = helper.Right;
        MyTree.Data = helper.Data;
    }
    if (helper.Left == null)
        helper = helper.Right;
    else
        helper = helper.Left;
}
```

BinaryTree representing each node in my tree.

Comment: FYI there's not need to use the `ref` keyword in `FindNode` since you don't reassign a vlaue to `myTree`

Comment: Have you confirmed that your `FindNode` method works properly/as intended?

Comment: FindNode work perfect, it return node with value from RemoveValue method

Comment: I want to remove only one node ( in my tree I can't have two the same values )

Comment: As a side not, you can make those two methods `static` methods of the `BinaryTree<T>` class.

Comment: you are not using the result which is `helper`. you need to return helper or set it to `myTree` at end of the method

Comment: But iI have a reference from myTree in helper so they don't pointing(referencing) on the same part of class and when i change some in one variable the other one have this change too ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight clean up of you code with suggestions on how I think `RemoveValue` should work. I leave it up to you to finish the implementation.

```
public class BinaryTree<T>
{
    public T Data;
    public BinaryTree<T> Left, Right;
    public BinaryTree()
    {
        this.Left = null;
        this.Right = null;
    }

    public static BinaryTree<T> FindNode(T value, BinaryTree<T> myTree)
    {
        if (myTree == null)
            return null;
        else
        {
            int result = Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(value, myTree.Data);
            if (result == 0)
                return myTree;
            else if (result > 0)
                return FindNode(value, myTree.Right);
            else if (result < 0)
                return FindNode(value, myTree.Left);
        }
        return myTree;
    }

    public static void RemoveValue(T value, ref BinaryTree<T> myTree)
    {
        if (myTree == null)
            return;
        BinaryTree<T> treeNodeToRemove = FindNode(value, myTree);

        // First case: The node to remove has a single subtree
        if(treeNodeToRemove.Left == null ^ treeNodeToRemove.Right == null)
        {
            // We need to change the Left||Right reference of our parent to us...
        }
        // Second case: Both subtrees are null
        else if (treeNodeToRemove.Left == null && treeNodeToRemove.Right == null)
        {
            // We need to change the reference of our parent to null
        }
        // Third case: Both subtrees are full
        else
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Also here [is a link](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/T26/del-from-bst.html) I used that outlines the three cases.

Comment: Nothing much, just easier to read and with some logical changes to the structure. I just gave the same effort you did with the question. Yours "doesn't work" so mine doesn't either. This just gets us away from talking about the stuff we are in the comments on the question to the real issue of the method itself.